# Duplicate single char with the shortest keys combinations

Tags: cut-copy-paste

Lets say I have `"string"` and I want to dupplicate the double quotes. What is the shortest way to do it?.

I have done a search of double quotes using `/"`.
Then I navigate to the different occurences using `n` command and I apply this sequence of commands: `xPP`

I know this can be done also using these commands: `xPp` or `xP.`

Excluding macros and function definitions, is there a shorter key combination to achieve that?

Comment: What about `:s/"/""/gc` ?

Comment: I would also do `/"` then `s""<esc>` then `n.`, `n.`, ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do:

1. `/"` to search for the character
2. `yl` to copy the character
3. `p` to paste the character
4. then alternate between `n` and `.` to search and replace

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind using the plugin [vim-surround](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) it can be as short as `ysa""`:

- Put your cursor on the word you want to surround
- `ys` is the vim surround command
- `a"` is the text object to operate on, it could also be `aW`
- `"` is the character you want to use to surround the text object

And as a bonus you can to the reverse operation i.e removing the surrounding quotes with `ds"`

---

Without a plugin I would go for `:s/"[^"]\+"/"&"`

- `"[^"]\+"` allows you to capture a quote followed by any number of characters other than `"` followed by `"`
- `"&"` here `&` is a reference to the whole matched text which as to be surrounded by two quotes.

Comment: There are so very few vim plugins i feel are essential (ie most of them accomplish something that can be done natively with a little effort, but make the task smoother). Vim-surround, while technically just smoothing it’s tasks, is one of these essential few for it’s “vimminess” and *constant usefulness*.